# How should I check for dupplicate entity in an object collection?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've been reading this post : [Doctrine - how to check if a collection contains an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073982/doctrine-how-to-check-if-a-collection-contains-an-entity)

But I actually don't like the solution, as, doctrine already provide the [contains()](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/latest/index.html#contains) method, which have the advantage to keep logic directly into the object, and then to [not load EXTRA_LAZY collections entirely](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html).

So here a `Cart` Entity own a CartProduct collection as is :

```
/**
 * ...
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CartRepository")
 */
abstract class Cart implements InheritanceInterface{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CartProduct", mappedBy="cart", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private Collection $cartProducts;
    ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cartProducts = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...
}
```

(CartProduct have to be an Entity look at this [simplify EA model](https://app.lucidchart.com/documents/view/6d4cdbd9-4e26-4979-aa0f-de09a2b93018). That's a [standard way to proceed](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/many-to-many-extra-fields) for related entity holding extra fields)

Now I want to add a new `ProductCart` Entity to my `Cart` class.

So I'm adding this method (generated by Symfony `make:entity`) :

```
abstract class Cart implements InheritanceInterface{
...
    public function addCartProduct(CartProduct $cartProduct): self
    {
        if(!$this->getCartProducts()->contains($cartProduct)) {
            $this->cartProducts->add($cartProduct);
            $cartProduct->setCart($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }
...
```

And then I test this code :

```
    public function testAddCartProduct()
    {
        $cart = new ShoppingCart($this->createMock(ShoppingCartState::class));
        $cart_product = new CartProduct();
        $cart_product->setProduct(new Product(self::NO_.'1', new Group('1')));
        $cart->addCartProduct($cart_product);
        $cart_product2 = new CartProduct();
        $cart_product2->setProduct(new Product(self::NO_.'1', new Group('1')));
        $cart->addCartProduct($cart_product2);
        $this->assertCount(1, $cart->getCartProducts());
    }
```

But when I run this test, it fail :

> Failed asserting that actual size 2 matches expected size 1.

So I check, and the `Cart`.`cartProducts` *Collection* have two product which are exactly the same objects.

As it's an `ArrayCollection`, I suppose that it just use this method :

```
namespace Doctrine\Common\Collections;
class ArrayCollection implements Collection, Selectable {
    ...
    public function contains($element)
    {
        return in_array($element, $this->elements, true);
    }
```

So well, of course in this case it is just return false, And the objects are considered to be different.

So now, I wish I could use `PersistentCollection` instead of `ArrayCollection` when implementing the `Collection` object , because the `PersistentCollection`.`contains()` method looks better.

```
abstract class Cart implements InheritanceInterface{
...
 public function __construct()
    {
--      $this->cartProducts = new ArrayCollection();
++      $this->cartProducts = new PersistentCollection(...);
    }
}
```

But this require an `EntityManager` as a parameter, so, seams a little bit overkill to give an EntityManager to an Entity object...

So I finally, I don't know what is the better way to check for a dupplicate entity inside a collection.

Of course, I could implement myself a thing like :

```
abstract class Cart implements InheritanceInterface{
...
    public function addCartProduct(CartProduct $cartProduct): self
    {
        if(!$this->getCartProducts()->filter(
            function (CartProduct $cp)use($cartProduct){
                return $cp->getId() === $cartProduct->getId();
            })->count()) {
            $this->cartProducts->add($cartProduct);
            $cartProduct->setCart($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }
...
```

But it'll require to load every Entity and I really don't like the idea.

Comment: I wonder if I'm not just at the wrong layer of the application to put this kind of repsponsibility. Maybe the Entity don't care about a product already exist or not.. Maybe it's the responsibility of the Controller to make a call to the Repository to check for a dupplicate **before** updating the Entity and adding a new ProductCart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I agree with your comment, I don't think the entity itself should have the responsibility to ensure there is no duplicate.

The entity cannot make a request like a repository could, and I don't see how you can be sure there is no duplicate in the database without querying it.

Calling `contains` will not trigger a fetch in your case, this means the collection will stay as is, which is not what you want anyway because you could have a previously persisted duplicate that will not be part of the collection because you marked it as `EXTRA_LAZY`.

You also don't want to fetch all the entities of the collection (and transform the results into objects) just to check if you have a collision.

So IMHO you should create a method in the repository of the entity to check for duplicates, a simple `SELECT COUNT(id)`.

Then there is your real problem.

The way you make your test will never find a collision. When you do:

```php
$cart = new ShoppingCart($this->createMock(ShoppingCartState::class));
$cart_product = new CartProduct();
$cart_product->setProduct(new Product(self::NO_.'1', new Group('1')));
$cart->addCartProduct($cart_product);
$cart_product2 = new CartProduct();
$cart_product2->setProduct(new Product(self::NO_.'1', new Group('1')));
$cart->addCartProduct($cart_product2);
$this->assertCount(1, $cart->getCartProducts());
```

You are creating **two** instances of `CartProduct`, that's why the call to `contains` doesn't find anything.

Because `contains` checks for the object reference, not the content, like you can see in its implementation:

```php
public function contains($element)
{
    return in_array($element, $this->elements, true);
}
```

So in your test case what you're really testing is:

```php
in_array(new CartProduct(), [new CartProduct()], true);
```

which will always return false.

Comment: Thank you, I needed confirmation that my way of thinking was correct. So I conclude that the function ``contains()`` cannot be trusted. I think that this function could lead a number of beginners (like me) to think that the collections are safe from duplicates.

Comment: `contains` only tells you if the actual "thing" you are testing is already in the collection. If it's an object it must be the same **instance**. You can trust it as long as you think about how and where the object you are testing have been created and you know the loading state of the collection.